# Displaying Group values when they don't appear in a Dataset

Tags: sql, reporting-services, dataset, grouping

I was recently given an assignment to emulate my organization's Timekeeping system, and then replicate the timesheet report we get each week.

I've designed a database with a TimeEntry table. It contains columns for the amount of hours, and FK relationships with both a User Table and an Entry Type table.

Inside the Entry Type table, there are 3 bit columns. Using these, I can determine the Category of the Entry for the report I create. Here's the query I use for the Dataset in SqlServer Data Tools:

```
SELECT u.Name AS UserName, 
       et.EntryDescription, 
       p.Name as ProjectName, 
       a.Desciption, 
       d.Date, 
       e.[Hours] 
  FROM [Entry] as e
       JOIN [Day] AS d
            ON d.DayID = e.DayID
       JOIN [User] AS u
            ON u.UserID = d.UserID
       JOIN Project AS p
            ON p.ProjectID = e.ProjectID
       JOIN EntryType AS et
            ON et.EntryTypeID = e.EntryTypeIDs
       JOIN Activity as A
            ON a.ActivityID = e.ActivityID
```

In SSRS the wizard's matrix can mostly sort this out. There's a RowGroup based on UserName, and a ColumnGroup based on Entry Description.

Here's my problem: For both groups, if there isn't an entry, this query obviously can't add them to the matrix. For instance, an employee who hasn't logged time in the system for the week doesn't appear as a User with zero hours, instead they don't appear at all. Likewise, if no time entry has been entered for a particular EntryType then it doesn't appear as a column.

I'm very new to SSRS (clearly) and would like to figure out how exactly to make sure that all possible elements of a group appear in the matrix. Should I create new Datasets for Users and EntryTypes? If I do, how do I use those possible values for their respective groups in the original dataset? Is there a way to craft the query in this dataset to ensure I get all the possible values from both of these tables?

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342369/populating-with-0-when-data-in-ssrs-does-not-exist/... Basically you can include all rows with `LEFT JOIN` when generating the DataSet or hard code the required columns into the report.

Comment: @IanPreston that's a very helpful link (I can hardcode the columns, for instance). Am I incorrect in thinking that a left join will not work since my primary table is "Entry" rather than User? So to get this to work, I'd have to make my select statement from Users and build my joins from there?

Comment: You can always just change the order of the tables in the query, put User first then left join from there. Since you are using all inner joins at the moment, order is irrelevant is your current query. You could keep the order and use right joins, but no one likes right joins.

Comment: Great! I've changed the query and now it WORKS. I'll add it in an answer here whenever I'm allowed to.

The architect who assigned this to me suggested that left outer joins like this are expensive, so eventually I'm going to cut out a table (Day) from the DB/Data Model, and use subselects and left outer joins for just the info I need (User, EntryType) while using traditional joins for the other needed tables.