# How to hardcode a value even if it doesn't exist and show "0" or "" in SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have multiple statuses and I have created a matrix based on those statuses. Whenever the logic doesn't apply to a status, the status will not show in the matrix. Which is understable but does anyone know how to hardcode it in the matrix so that the status header will show even if there aren't any records related to the status?

here is a brief example of my code:

```
SELECT  YYYYMM
       ,Status = CASE WHEN Date1 IS NOT NULL 
                       AND Date2 IS NOT NULL
                       AND Date3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Open'
                     WHEN Date4 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Closed'
                     WHEN Date5 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Pending'
                ELSE 'N/A'
INTO #Status
FROM Table1

SELECT  YYYYMM
       ,Status
       ,SubStatus = CASE WHEN [Status] = 'Open'
                          AND Date1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Open 1'
                         WHEN [Status] = 'Open'
                          AND Date2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Open 2'
                         WHEN [Status] = 'Open'
                          AND Date3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Open 3'
                     ELSE NULL
INTO #Final
FROM #Status

SELECT  YYYYMM
       ,Status
       ,SubStatus
       ,COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM #Final
GROUP BY YYYYMM, Status, SubStatus
```

Results should be similar to:

```
YYYYMM    Status    SubStatus    Count
201405    Closed    NULL          10
201405    Open      Open 1        4
201405    Open      Open 2        6
201407    Open      Open 3        12
201407    Pending   NULL          8
```

My metrix looks like this:

```
                  Open                 Closed       Pending
YYYYMM   Open 1 | Open 2 | Open 3
201405      4        6       12          10
201407                                                 8
```

My metrix is grouped by YYYYMM and Satus --> SubStatus. In case, if there isn't any value for Pending status, the status will not display but I want the status to display even if there isnt nay value. Anyway to hardcode it? I have tried this expression but it doesn't work:
    =IIF(StatusField.Value = "Pending", SUM(COUNT), "")

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342369/populating-with-0-when-data-in-ssrs-does-not-exist/ ?

Comment: Hi,
If Ian's link does not work...
I assume you are expecting to see the 12 in the cell below where is currently appears, is this correct?
Also, could you provide a small sample of the contents of Table1